# How to automatically close a wait key window with os.subprocess.run()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I would like to run an executable with os.subprocess.run(). The executable does:

1. First displays an image in a window(cv::imshow)
2. Waits for a key to be pressed by the user to close the window.(cv::waitKey)
3. Outputs a stdout that I actually need.

I don't need the image window and since I am going to use it in a loop I can not close it with a key every time. The stdout is the only thing that I need.

I have used the following code but the image windows kept coming up.

```
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= (
    subprocess.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
)
startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
```

Any ideas on how to suppress this image window?

Comment: If it reads the keystroke from standard input, `input='\n'` should suffice. This will obviously not bypass the display of the image entirely; you would have to modify the program which displays the image to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, `input='\n'` does not works.

Comment: Then you'll _probably_ have to synthesize a keystroke event for whatever GUI backend CV is running on.